# An anchor name (id name) in the address bar

Tags: urls

I have a long website with anchors to specific sections of the page. The menu and scrolling to the sections work fine. However, in the address bar, I can see just static URL. For example www.websitename.com. In the address bar, I would like to have an anchor name (id section name) like that: www.websitename.com/name
Is anyone know how I can achieve that?

Thank you in advance
Sebastian

Comment: Your question is most probably off-topic for WP:SE as this is not really a WP problem. Please search for yourself how to use anchors in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is www.websitename.com/#sectionName ?
If you use anchor name or ID to scroll to section, it should be shown in url bar.

```
<a href="#SectionName"> Go to Section Div </a>
```

And your div ID

```
<div id="SectionName"> Content </div>
```

After you clicked, It should show ID name on URL bar. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Yes, this is what I want. I used anchor id to link the menu to the section but unfortunately, I don't get anchor name in the URL.

So, for example, my anchor is #contact and in the address bar, I am getting just "normal" address of the page. www.name.com instead of www.name.com/#contact.